How to twist an object's sides

Essentially, I've made this twisted mobius strip and I was wondering if anyone has any way to twist it where the sides of the shape twist and rotate.

if it's a curve i guess you need to convert to mesh then cut off and rotate the mesh so that the sides are twisted
